# Unable to fix Hg case-folding collision error with Mercurial's guide

Tags: mercurial, checkout, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Is there a problem with Mercurial's guide for fixing case-folding collisions or is there a problem with the way I am implementing the solution.

The solution as provided on the [Mercurial wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FixingCaseCollisions) is as follows:

> ```
> hg clone -U repo repair
> cd repair
>
> hg debugsetparents <bad revision>
> hg debugrebuildstate
> ```
>
> At this point, Mercurial will think you have the bad revision checked
>   out and all the files are missing (status '!'). To fix the repo, we
>   simply have to do:
>
> ```
> hg rm -A <file causing the collision>
> ```
>
> Now hg st should show the troublesome file in state 'R' and all other
>   files in state '!'. Now we can check in our fix:
>
> ```
> hg ci -m"fix case collision"
> ```
>
> To get all our files back, we just check out again:
>
> ```
> hg co tip
> ```

The problem files are: `SomeFile.bash` and `Somefile.bash`. I originally had `Somefile.bash` and I would like it to now be `SomeFile.bash`. Also to note, version 157 is happy, no collision, but version 158 is where I have introduced the collision. The head of the repository is currently at revision 160.

I have implemented this solution as follows:

```
hg clone -U my-repo-url repair
cd repair
hg debugsetparent 160
hg debugrebuildstate
hg status (reveals that everything is 'missing' (!))
hg rm -A Somefile.bash (responds that SomeFile.bash has been removed, notice case change)
hg ci -m "Fixed the collision... I hope."
hg co tip

hg update -C tip
```

According to the guide, this should have removed the case-folding collision and brought the rest of the missing files back, yet another `hg status` reveals that everything is still missing (!).

**Edit**: By appending that last command (the `update`) to the existing commands, I was able to recover the missing files which solved the remainder of the problem.

**Note**: I had to use the most recent 'problem' version for `<bad revision>` to fix this problem (that was 160 in my case).

Comment: Please provide the **exact** sequence of commands you're issuing (including the real revision numbers).  Assuming you don't have something awful like `inotify` turned on it may be that you've misinterpretend what to use for `<bad revision>`.

Comment: Refer to the **edit** I have supplied above.

Comment: @Ry4an did my above edits shed any light on why this process isn't working for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
hg update -C tip
```

That should bring the files back.  If not, try reverting everything:

```
hg revert -r tip -a
```

Comment: Executing the command from the first part of your answer (`hg update -C tip`) after the above commands seems to have done the trick. This pulled in all the missing files. Thanks!